# How can I compare an index value of a list item with all index of same list

Tags: c#, list

i have a list which is iterating multiple times. it is having rangename as item. My requirement is perform an action when rangename at any index of this list is equal to rangename at some other index. i am using the following code.

```
 var bList = new List<Budget.budget_data>(); 
       for (int z = 0; z < bList.Count; z++)
   {
   if (bList [z].Range == bList.Where(a => bList.Any(x => x.Range ==x.Range)))
 {
     //need to perform action
 }
```

}

which is giving error. How to compare one index value of a list's item with all index on same list .

Answer (score 0):

Not too clearly asked, I feel, but you could try this:

```
var bList = new List<Budget.budget_data>();
// ...
var z = ...;

for (var x = 0; x < bList.Count; ++x)
{
  if (x == z)
    continue;

  if (bList[z].Range == bList[x].Range)
  {
    //need to perform action
  }
}
```

This performs the action one time for each index `x` for which there is a match, so the action can run many times. If you just want one execution of the action, you may finish the `if` block with a `break;` statements (exits the loop completely).

Note: This assumes that the type of `.Range` is such that it is reasonable to use `==`. What is the declared type of `.Range`?

---

I may have misunderstood the question. If you want to determine whether there are any duplicates at all, you can:

```
var bList = new List<Budget.budget_data>();
// ...
var uniqueRangeValues = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (var b in bList)
{
  if (!uniqueRangeValues.Add(b.Ranges))
  {
    // perform action

    break; // omit if you want to perform the action several times
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Range is of String Type.What should be var z= ?

Comment: What is var z=...?

Comment: @Ram I thought you had a particular `z` from the outset? I may have misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks Jeppe Stig Nielsen. the solution suggested by you is working .

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, you want to perform some action when two Ranges are equal in your list. Following should work for you.

```
var bList = new List<Budget.budget_data>();
        for (var i = 0; i < bList.Count; i++)
        {
            for (var j = i + 1; j < bList.Count; j++)
            {
                if (bList[i].Range == bList[j].Range)
                {
                    //Perform your action
                }
            }
        }
```

This will perform your action if there is any duplicate **Range** in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to find duplicates however without clearly knowing what you are trying to achieve its difficult to help you find an adequate solution to your problem.

Using some of the details you've provided, below is a generic solution for looping through duplicates.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var budgets = new List<Budget>()
    {
        new Budget(){ Id = 1, Range = "A" },
        new Budget(){ Id = 2, Range = "B" },
        new Budget(){ Id = 3, Range = "C" },
        new Budget(){ Id = 4, Range = "C" },
        new Budget(){ Id = 5, Range = "A" }
    };

    var duplicateBudgetGroups = budgets.GroupBy(budget => budget.Range).Where(group => group.Count() > 1);

    foreach (var duplicateBudgets in duplicateBudgetGroups)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Duplicate Range {0}", duplicateBudgets.Key);
        foreach (var budget in duplicateBudgets)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Budget {{ Id = {0}, Range = {1} }}", budget.Id.ToString(), budget.Range);
        }
    }
}

class Budget {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Range { get; set; }
}
```

I've added this to dotnetfiddle so you can see it working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/65gF6f